# How to automate a process by pulling elements from a data frame in R -looping with a string?

Tags: r, string, loops, syntax, apply

I am trying to automate a process instead of individually compute PPCC values for a large number of test cases.  The details of my functions do not matter (though for reference I'm using Lmomco), my issue is either putting this into a loop or somehow using plyr or apply to repeat over and over. I do not know how to automate the string. For example I have sorted data by "M" parameter:

```
testx.100cv1<-by(x.cv1$first_year,x.cv1$M,sort)
```

I then apply a function here:

```
testexp<-lapply(testx.100cv1,parexp)
```

Now I want to do something to each "M", where in the example below, M = 1.02.  Right now, I am manually changing this value and then recomputing for every M (and I have a lot of them).  I'm looking for a way to write this M value into a loop so it reads it automatically.

```
exp<-quaexp(plotpos,testexp$'1.02')
PPCCexp<-cor(exp,testx.100cv1$'1.02')
```

I want to compute PPCC values for many distributions, so without automating, this will take over my life for a week. 
Thanks!

Comment: Is `lapply(testexp, function(x) quaexp(plotpos,x))` what you are looking for?

Comment: hard to test, what about `Map(quaexp, plotpos, testexp)`? you can use map/mapply and others to do this for you, ex `l <- list(1:5, 6:10); Map(sample, size = 5, x = l)`